# How can I optimally concat a list of chars to a string?

Tags: python, string

The data:

```
list = ['a','b','x','d','s']
```

I want to create a string str = "abxds". How can I do that?

Right now I am doing something like:

```
str = ""
for i in list:
    str = str + i
print(str)
```

I know strings are immutable in Python and this will create 7 string object. And this goes out of my memory when I do thousands of times.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: You should avoid using "list" as the name of your list as list is a built-in (and same for "str")

Comment: `str` objects are _immutable_ in Python, which is why it creates a new `str` object for each concatenation operation.

Comment: i am sorry, typo, Strings are immutable

Comment: @Naoh: I will not use list or str

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
>>> theListOfChars = ['a', 'b', 'x', 'd', 's']
>>> ''.join(theListOfChars)
'abxds'
```

BTW, *don't use `list` or `str` as variable names* as they are names of built-in functions already.

(Also, there is no `char` in Python. A "character" is just a string of length 1. So the `''.join` method works for list of strings as well.)

Comment: Is the is most efficient method out there?

Comment: Speed difference:  
without join: 1.01871395111
with join: 0.609759092331

Comment: I am sorry, could not follow what you meant. You mean to say I can embed some other code into this and make it faster?

Comment: @Ringo: Yeah you can make a specific C interface, but it is a mess to do and wouldn't have very large gain over `''.join`.

Comment: What you should do is use `.join()`. Then, if your code still isn't fast enough, profile it. If the `.join()` turns out to be the bottleneck, *then* consider writing a C module to replace it. A C version could indeed be significantly faster than `.join()` if you can assume that the contents of the list will be single ASCII characters.

Answer (score 4):

KennyTM's answer is great.  Also, if you wanted to make them comma separated or something, it'd be:

```
",".join(characterlist)
```

This would result in "a,b,x,d,s"

Answer (score 2):

The thing you're looking for is `str.join()`:

```
>>> L = ['a','b','x','d','s']
>>> ''.join(L)
'abxds'
```

(Don't name your variable `list`, it's a builtin name.)