# an elegant way to concatenate a list of chars in a string in Python

Tags: python, string, list, char, concatenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I optimally concat a list of chars to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166641/how-can-i-optimally-concat-a-list-of-chars-to-a-string)

I have a list of chars:

```
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Is there a way to concatenate the elements of such list in a string 'hello' that does not require c-like 'for' loop? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the usual way of concatenating strings in Python:

```
''.join(list_of_chars)
```

In fact, that's the [*recommended*](http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/) way - for readability and efficiency reasons. For example:

```
''.join(['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'])
=> 'hello'
```

Comment: Of particular interest is that python won't even let you try to use `sum` on it: `>>> sum(['h','e','l','l','o'],'')`

Comment: @mgilson, it will if you say pretty please: `sum(['h','e','l','l','o'], type('',(),{'__add__': lambda s, o: o})())`.

Comment: @eryksun -- I think that's a little above and beyond "pretty please" ... None the less, that's incredible.  That gave me a big smile this morning.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 4):

[str.join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
>>> list('hello')
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> ''.join(_)
'hello'
```

It's effectively:

```
from operator import add
reduce(add, ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'])
```

But optimised for strings, it also **only allows strings**, otherwise it raises a `TypeError`

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Use [str.join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
>>> chars = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> ''.join(chars)
'hello'
```